# how to draw a work flow or data flow chart using jfreechart?

Tags: java, jfreechart

everyone! I want to show an algorithm process on the web page. I know that jfreechart is good at drawing pie chart,bar chart and so on. But all these graphs are statistics related. Can anybody tell me how to draw a flow like chart with more convenient way? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[`GanttRenderer`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/category/GanttRenderer.html) is good for work flows, but you might browse the [demos](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/jfreechart-1.0.13-demo.jnlp) for other ideas.